# System.DllNotFoundException in OpenTK.dll

Tags: c#, dll, opentk

So I'm very new to OpenGl and 3D programming in general, i'm trying to setup a basic project with OpenTK, it was working fine at the sart but now i get this errors when the program calls the constructor of the GameWindow class.

```
        public Window() : base(1280, 720, GraphicsMode.Default, "OpenGL", OpenTK.GameWindowFlags.Default, DisplayDevice.Default, 3, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContextFlags.Debug)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("gl version: " + GL.GetString(StringName.Version));
    }
```

and here are the error I get:

`Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in OpenTK.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in OpenTK.dll`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `System.BadImageFormatException` means that something is trying to load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process, or vice versa.

Comment: Tanks, by compiling in x64 I don't get that error anymore, but I still get the missingDLL exception

Comment: What is the entire exception message including stacktrace?

Comment: The exception doesn't get thrown for some reason I think it's managed by OpenTK or something, I only see the message in the output window on VS, I only know that it gets thrown when i do: new Window().Run(60); in the Main method

Comment: I put the solution on github if can help: https://github.com/Morphisor/3dGameEngine-CSharp

Comment: I have the same problem on VS 2017. The program doesn't fail but issues the exception message in the output window. Has no one seen and solved this?